# Datadog agent do not send data

Tags: amazon-ec2, datadog

I run into an issue with my Datadog agent. I installed Agent version 7.35.0 on an EC2 ubuntu machine. After I restarted the agent I got this error:

> Apr 10 11:24:24 ip-10-100-0-33 agent[9951]: 2022-04-10 11:24:24 UTC | CORE | WARN |(pkg/collector/python/datadog_agent.go:124 in LogMessage) | disk:e5dffb8bef24336f |(disk.py:136) | Unable to get disk metrics for /sys/kernel/debug/tracing: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/sys/kernel/debug/tracing'. You can exclude this mountpoint in the settings if it is invalid.

From what I've seen on threads, they gave this answer:

> Can you add "tracefs" to the "file_system_blacklist" configuration to see if that unblocks you? We can add it by default if it does.

But I do not completely understand this answer, and I am not sure what should I change to fix this issue.

If anyone experiences this kind of thing and can help me it would be super helpful
Thank you!

Comment: This is not an error, its just a warning, linux system try to mount /sys/kernel/debug/tracing to receive logs events from the system. 
Have you reviewed your installation process? have you created your service directory with a conf.yaml inside?

Comment: Hi for everyone who got the same log - I've been reinstalling the DD-agent and modified the conf.yaml file with the right keys and it is working!

Comment: @eylonlevi which directory for the conf?

Answer (score 2):

With Datadog Agent 7:

```
mv /etc/datadog-agent/conf.d/disk.d/conf.yaml.default /etc/datadog-agent/conf.d/disk.d/conf.yaml
```

Then in `/etc/datadog-agent/conf.d/disk.d/conf.yaml`, uncomment `file_system_global_exclude` and underneath it add `- tracefs`:

```
init_config:
    file_system_global_exclude:
        - tracefs
```